# Display none in table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I do a display none in div with id="NoveMeses" if all elements from h3 show "N.A"?

If h3 from div row1 and row2 show me the span="N.A", I want to display none the div NoveMeses.

There is my code using AngularJs

```
<div id="NoveMeses" data-ng-if=$odd class="tableRowOdd" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '9M'">
          <div class="tableCellContent20">
                   <h3 class="cellTextType" ><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
          </div>

          <div id="row1" class="tableCellContent20">
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="!item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
          </div>

          <div id="row2" class="tableCellContent20">
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="!item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if item.TipoOWS === 'Datas, you want to hide 'NoveMeses' div?

Comment: @NagaSaiA no, if data-ng-show="!item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'" in "row1" and "row2" div, I want to hide 'NoveMeses' div

Comment: item.TipoOWS === 'Datas is same as !item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas right?

Comment: @NagaSaiA theoretically it should, but no. It does not display me the same item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I untherstand you you want to hide the NoveMeses div if your h3's span text is N.A.

So a simple javascript like this would make it happen

```js
var nove_meses = document.getElementById('NoveMeses');
var h3s = document.querySelectorAll('.cellTextValue span');
    for(var i = 0; i < h3s.length; i++) {
        console.log(h3s[i].innerText);
        if(h3s[i].innerText == 'N.A.') {
            nove_meses.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="NoveMeses" data-ng-if=$odd class="tableRowOdd" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '9M'">
    <div class="tableCellContent20">
        <h3 class="cellTextType" >
            <span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="row1" class="tableCellContent20">
        <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'">
            <span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span
        </h3>
        <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="!item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'">
            <span>N.A.</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="tableCellContent20">
        <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'">
            <span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span>
        </h3>
        <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="!item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'">
            <span>N.A.</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please view the snippet, I even added the classname to limit the span number

Comment: It worked, but it just don't display none the NoveMeses div